# How remove a specific string from an element's text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove **12:00:00 AM** from following string.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>1/11/2016 12:00:00 AM - 1/13/2016 12:00:00 AM</p>
</div>
```

The results should be:

> 1/11/2016  - 1/13/2016

How can I remove just the **12:00:00 AM** from complete string all occurrences of it.

```
$('.modal-body > p').text().remove("12:00:00 AM");
```

Comment: If you are getting these time stamps from a database you may want to format them using either SQL or your server-side script.

Comment: @PeterKA you are right I need a quick fix for now. I will ask a separate question for that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqn23v64/)

```
$('.modal-body > p').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/12:00:00 AM/g, '');
});
```

Result:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>1/11/2016  - 1/13/2016</p>
</div>
```

If you only want to replace the first occurrence, just remove the `g` flag.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace